# Android wearableListenerService invoke method from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, wear-os, public

Is there a way to call a non-static method of an activity from a wearableListenerService?
(Binding the service is not possible for wearableListenerService. Because the method onBind() is final.)

Simplified example:

Service.class:

```
public class MyService extends WearableListenerService { 
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent){
        myActivityMethod();
    }
    ...
}
```

Activity.class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   public void myActivityMethod(){
      //do sth.
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could `Broadcast` an event and register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity`. You could also connect the `GooglePlayClient` in your Activity and let it handle the `onMessageReceived` event, if the current activity is the current at screen